# Having Issue in reading csv file in pandas, data is not showing correctly

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have csv file which was encoding in "UTF-8" but when I try to read that file I face multiple problem we I try to read the file using this

```
df = pd.read_csv("filename.csv",encoding="utf-8")
```

I receive an error which is **'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: invalid continuation byte**

but after solving this issue by using **encoding="ISO-8859-1"** i receive this ERROR 
**Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 8, saw 4** 
which was again i solve it using

```
df = pd.read_csv("filename.csv",encoding="ISO-8859-1", error_bad_lines=False,lineterminator='\n')
```

I receive this warning **b'Skipping line 6: expected 4 fields, saw 6\nSkipping line 17: expected 4 fields, saw 5\n'**
and  I didn't receive my full data , I had 17 column in csv file and I get only 4
And When I check my data using

```
df
df.columns
```

I receive data like this

```
Index(['PK',
       'à¥ÇDO97*~§ÈÉ¸8ÀOíc
|n¦ÑäEøÿöéºóÀBÉÀ!$}íàÈé;{ìÐå[îñé2þ',
       '8æø(%£¦"Dô¹Ò4jÎ0u2jsÐ
ÊMYÞË´äúSì­´·· )fåÿ¹CÛöyÑó\tI<\ry',
       'ËôïfäÉÇÕß'],
      dtype='object')
```

In my csv file my data column name is not like this, acctually whole data is coming in this form and only showing 4 column but I had 17 columns in my csv file

Comment: Can you show a sample of the content of your csv file?

Comment: like this i had data in my csv file,suppose these are just the column name of my csv file

Comment: Post No,username,image,data,feedbackno,feedbackdata,feedbackusername,feedbackuserimage